# How to run a shell script on all amazon ec2 instances that are part of a autoscaling group?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, shell-scripting, autoscaling

Can anyone please tell me how to run a shell script on all the ec2 instances that are part of a auto scaling group.

The scenario is that i have a script that i want to run on many ec2 instances that are turned on automatically as part of auto scaling group. The native approach is ssh to each instance and run the script. I am looking for a way by which it can run automatically on all the instances when i run it on one of the ec2 instance or any better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1z0duk6

Comment: But we don't know the ip addresses of these servers as they are generated dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there are two approaches:

- Use the AWS API to determine the IP of all group members and then do SSH. -- This itself is possible on different levels, ranging from a shell script using aws-cli ([describe-auto-scaling-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-instances.html) and [describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)) to a more sophisticated setup e.g. with Python [boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/) and [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).
- Have all instances register themselves in some orchestration or cluster management tool, e.g. [serf](https://serfdom.io/) or [MCollective](https://puppetlabs.com/mcollective), and then use that channel to send commands to all group members.

Possibly third approach: do not explicitly run shell scripts at all, but have all instances get their setup from a Puppet or Chef server.

Comment: I need a shell script to determine all the IP of the instances of auto scaling group

Comment: Ankur, were you able to get the IP addresses of Instances of the AutoScaling group?

Comment: Ankur, you can get the find the anwer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/704806/how-to-get-autoscaling-group-instances-ip-adresses/705024#705024
I wrote small script for the same.